# How to put each line of a file in an array

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem with one of my bash scripts.

I have a file where is stored a list of email addresses line by line like so :

```
mail@adress1
mail@adress2
```

...

what I'd like to do is to actually put each line of the file in an array where each index corresponds to a line in the right order.

Comment: Did you try `readarray`/`mapfile`?

Comment: Is mapfile a GNU extension?

Comment: Well, mapfile is a bash builtin command, and bash is the GNU shell, so ... kinda.

Comment: Mh. Looks like my Bash is too old.

Comment: If you're on a Mac, look into [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, good idea. I shall update my Bash. :)

Answer (score 1):

For me mapfile was not available, you can also do this with potentially older Bash versions:

```
 set -f
 IFS=$'\n'                                                                                                                                             
 arr=($(<foo.txt))
```

Comment: You'll want to add `set -f` there, so you don't get any unwanted filename expansions due to the unquoted content.

Comment: @glennjackman: Oh yes, sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To read the lines of a file into an array:

```sh
mapfile -t myArray < myFile
```

or

```sh
myArray=()
while IFS= read -r line || [[ "$line" ]] ; do
    myArray+=( "$line" )
done < myFile
```

---

To read the fields of a line into an array: use `read` with `-a` and a "herestring" `<<<`

```sh
# suppose: line="foo,bar,baz"
IFS=, read -r -a fields <<< "$line"
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution worked for me, I didn't know such tool existed, I was stuck with my loops... I was wondering if I could use mapfile to fill an array with lists of words in column this time (I'm not asking you the solution, that wouldn't be fair, just if it' possible or not tu use mapfile again). Thanks again

Comment: You can use `read -a` to split a line into words

Comment: Yes, I just added that to the answer